# Миграция Room при добавлении полей

Tags: android, android-room

Есть БД (готовая из `assests`) с полями `bluda, products`.. Изначально приложение было написано используя `SQLiteOpenHelper`, но я решил переписать используя `Room`.

поднял версию с 1 до 2 и написал миграцию `MiGRATION_1_2`

Затем решил в таблицу products добавить поля icon и image (оба поля содержат названия изображений, для вывода в `RecyclerView`). Написал миграцию `MIGRATION_2_3` и поднял версию с 2 до 3, но почему-то в `RecyclerView` вместо картинок ничего не выводится, в логах если попробовать получить данные из поля image выводится `null`. Как правильно написать миграцию, чтобы новая версия БД из `assests` (с полями icon и image заполненными) без проблем появилась у пользователей?

AppDatabase

```
@Database(entities = {Bludo.class, Products.class}, version = 3, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase instance;

    public abstract ProductsDao productsDao();
    public abstract BludoDao bludoDao();

    private static final String DB_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                    .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1,2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE bluda_new (_id INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT, ingredients TEXT," +
                    "description TEXT, icon TEXT, image TEXT, favorite TEXT, region TEXT, productsID INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(_id))");

            database.execSQL(
                    "INSERT INTO bluda_new (_id, name, ingredients, description, icon, image, favorite, region, productsID)" +
                            "SELECT _id, name, ingredients, description, icon, image, favorite, region, productsID FROM bluda");

            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE bluda");

            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE bluda_new RENAME TO bluda");


            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE products_new (_id INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(_id))");

            database.execSQL(
                    "INSERT INTO products_new (_id, name)" +
                            "SELECT _id, name FROM products");

            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE products");

            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE products_new RENAME TO products");
        }
    };

    private static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2,3) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN icon TEXT");
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN image TEXT");


            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE products_new (_id INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT, icon TEXT, image TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(_id))");

            database.execSQL(
                    "INSERT INTO products_new (_id, name, icon, image)" +
                            "SELECT _id, name, icon, image FROM products");

            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE products");

            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE products_new RENAME TO products");
        }
    };
}
```

В полях icon и image данные точно есть. Если на чистое устройство установить в `RecyclerView` данные выводятся.

Comment: `AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory` - это из какой библиотеки? Надо разбираться с ней. Обычные миграции здесь не помогут - все манипуляции производятся внутри одной версии базы (и судя по всему старой).

Comment: эта библиотека https://github.com/daolq3012/AssetSQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: Если ещё актуально... Насколько я понял в глубоких корнях библиотеки лежит [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) и, соответственно, upgrade нужно делать как-то так же. Там есть кое-какое описание и демонстрационный модуль. Общий смысл в том, что нужно создать скрипт обновления, задать ему имя определённого формата и положить рядом с базой в ассеты.